# send: command not found - CentOS 6.2

Tags: linux, centos, command, send, fiware

I'm trying to execute the next script (run.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Rooms and Floors example

CEP=localhost:8080

. ../common.sh

# Send an updateContext request with Room temp
function sendRoomTemp() #(url, floor, room, value)
{
    payload='{
        "contextElements": [
            {
                "type": "Room",
                "isPattern": "false",
                "id": "'$3'",
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "temperature",
                        "type": "double",
                        "value": '$4'
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "floor",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "'$2'"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "updateAction": "APPEND"
    }'

    send $1 "v1/updateContext" "$payload"
}

echo "#1 First update CEP with RoomsAndFloors configuration"
CONFIG=`cat config.json`
updateConfig $CEP "$CONFIG"

echo ""
echo "#2 Then send T° of all the rooms to the CEP every 5 sec"

for temp in 12 14 18 20 24 19; do

    echo ""
    echo "# Wait between temperatures updates..."
    echo ""
    sleep 5

    for room in 1 2 3 4; do
        for floor in 1 2 3; do
            # compute a unique temp for each room
            t=$(($temp + (2*$floor) + $room))
            echo " - Send updateContext for Room$floor$room with T°=$t"
            out=$(sendRoomTemp $CEP "Floor$floor" "Room$floor$room" "$t")
            echo "   $out"
        done
    done
done
```

And when I execute `sh run.sh` I get:

```
 ....
 # Wait between temperatures updates...

 - Send updateContext for Room11 with T°=15
run.sh: line 34: send: command not found

 - Send updateContext for Room21 with T°=17
run.sh: line 34: send: command not found
....
```

The script is from FIWARE Cepheus tutorial https://fiware-cepheus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/1_RoomsAndFloors/index.html

My machine is CentOS 6.2

How I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I rewrite the script using another commands, it was the only solution that I can found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the examples `run.sh` scripts from inside the project directories (like `doc/examples/1_RoomsAndFloors`) as they depend on the presence of a `common.sh` file in the parent directory `doc/examples` that define the `send` function.

Comment: Yes, I found it some days ago, I forgot to post here sorry. Thanks :)